# Always Encryption is Not working for Join Queries

Tags: encryption, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

I am using the below query and companyname is encrypted in table4. I have enabled the column encryption setting in web config. But it throws error while executing the below query.

```
var companyname = (from user in testEntities.table1
                                    where user.email == "test@gmail.com"
                                join mapper in testEntities.table2 on customerId equals mapper.CustomerId into details
                                from company in details.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join type in testEntities.table3 on user.CustomerTypeId equals type.Id
                                join companycategory in testEntities.table4 on company.CompanyId equals companycategory.CompanyId into cateogryname
                                from companyname in cateogryname.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select (companyname.CompanyName == null || company.IsActive == false) ? type.Type : companyname.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Error**

Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with nvarchar(100) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_....', column_encryption_key_name = 'keyname', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'testdb')\r\nStatement(s) could not be prepared.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?